# How to set write permission for Bitnami Lamp Stack

Tags: bitnami

I have installed Bitnami Lamp Stack on AWS. Installation was very quick and smooth and I was able to quickly get the bitnami welcome page. 
PHP Hello World was successful and uploading files with Filezilla on the folder /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs was OK.
However PHP couldn't write a file on this folder with the following php:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World<br>";
$data_table="this is a file write test";
$file = 'test.txt';
$handle = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo "The file {$file} can be written";
fwrite($handle, $data_table);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

In fact I got the error message Unable to open file!
Apparently the web server cannot write to the folder while Filezilla can do it.

I spent several hours trying to understand what is wrong. I tried to add the complete path, I changed temporarily chmod to 777, chown the group/user but no success.
I tried also other PHP applications that need to create files and even them did not work. Now I am quite frustrated. Any help is highly appreciated.

Roberto

Comment: I have a similar problem did you find the solution?

Comment: Nudge on this please